# Flutter_svg 2.x.x: How to Optimize BlendMode Algorithm Selection for Color Filter Property?

Tags: flutter, dart, svg

Hello fellow developers,

I am currently working on a project using Flutter and recently migrated to using the 2.x.x versions of the flutter_svg package. With this migration, I noticed the addition of new properties including the colorFilter which now requires the specification of a BlendMode algorithm type instead of just a color.

In most cases, using BlendMode.srcIn has given me the desired outcome, but I have encountered scenarios where this setting doesn't produce the results I am aiming for. Here are some details about my setup:

Flutter version: 3.10.6
Flutter_svg version: 2.0.7
Dart versiuon: 3.0.6

I am looking for advice on how to approach the selection of the BlendMode algorithm for different scenarios. Here are my specific questions:

How does each BlendMode algorithm affect the rendering of SVGs?
Are there any best practices for selecting a BlendMode based on the SVG attributes?
Can you provide examples of SVGs where a BlendMode other than srcIn would be more appropriate?
Thank you for your time and assistance

```
  Assets.icons.vector.lightSwitch.svg(
                                    colorFilter: const ColorFilter.mode(
                                      LwColors.secondaryColor,
                                      BlendMode.srcIn,
                                    ),
                                    height: 18,
                                  ),
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcNmF.png)